# Possible to rename a single type after import

Tags: scala

I have a situation where I want to include all types from a package. But one of these types clashes with my own type. Is it possible to import the whole package and then rename the type that clashes, after the fact, rather than individually import every type I need?

```
import somepackage.all._        // Contains A, B, C, etc
import somepackage.all.{A=>_A}  // Can I change the name of A after import?


class A {
 val a = new _A()
 val b = new B()
 val c = new C()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do both at the same time:

```
import somepackage.all.{A=>_A, _}
```

This will import everything except `A` which will be imported as `_A` instead.